# Get rid of following binary numbers but keep bitsize

Tags: c, unix

A bit new to C programming but I've made a binary mask in my program and there are following 0 on the wrong side.

```
Hex: 0x61
Binary Result: 0110000100000000
Binary Want:   0000000001100001
```

Is there a way I could shift them down to start from LSB instead?
Back of my mind is maybe, inverse the masking? Just a hunch.

Here's my function:

```
void printBin(char Key)
{
    int count;                                  
    int bits = 16;
    unsigned int mask = 1 << --bits;            

    for(count = 0; count <= bits; count++)      
        {
            if( Key & mask)
            {
                printw("1");
            }
            else
            {
                printw("0");
            }

        Key <<= 1;                              
        }
}
```

Comment: How should we answer that without seeing your code?

Comment: Good point... Edited~

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to print a binary string, when you loop over your number shifting the bits as you are, you end up with the bits in reverse order. While you can simply *print* the binary representation, it is far easier to save binary representation to a character string (so you can save it in the correct order) and return a pointer to a statically declared string.

The 3 functions below (1) `binstr` returns a simple binary string containing only the number of bits that make up the representation; (2) `binpad` returns a binary string padded to `sz` bits (so you can print all 64-bits of a 64-bit number, including the leading zeros) and (3) `binfmt` that returns a string padded to `sz` bits in `szs` bit groups separated by `sep` character.

To use the functions, simply declare the constants that tell whether your computer is 32/64 bit, that will set the number of `BITS_PER_LONG` along with `CHAR_BIT` (generally 8). Their use is shown below in the example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* CHAR_BIT */
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
# define CHAR_BIT  8
#endif

/* BUILD_64 */
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_LP64)
# define BUILD_64   1
#endif

/* BITS_PER_LONG */
#ifdef BUILD_64
# define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#else
# define BITS_PER_LONG 32
#endif
/* (note: adjust as required if not using x86/x86_64) */

char *binstr (unsigned long n);
char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz);
char *binfmt (unsigned long n, unsigned char sz, unsigned char szs, char sep);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    unsigned long v   = argc > 1 ? strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 237;
    unsigned long sz  = argc > 2 ? strtoul (argv[2], NULL, 10) : sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;
    unsigned long szs = argc > 3 ? strtoul (argv[3], NULL, 10) : CHAR_BIT;

    /* print 16-bit binary representation */
    printf ("\n binstr (%lu)\n %s\n", v, binstr (v));
    printf ("\n binpad (%lu, %lu)\n %s\n", v, sz/4, binpad (v, sz/4));
    printf ("\n binfmt (%lu, %lu, %hhu, %c)\n %s\n",
            v, sz/4, (unsigned)szs/2, '-', binfmt (v, sz/4, szs/2, '-'));

    /* print 32-bit binary representation */
    printf ("\n binpad (%lu, %lu)\n %s\n", v, sz/2, binpad (v, sz/2));
    printf ("\n binfmt (%lu, %lu, %hhu, %c)\n %s\n",
            v, sz/2, (unsigned)szs, '-', binfmt (v, sz/2, szs, '-'));

    /* print 64-bit binary representation */
    printf ("\n binpad (%lu, %lu)\n %s\n", v, sz, binpad (v, sz));
    printf ("\n binfmt (%lu, %lu, %hhu, %c)\n %s\n",
            v, sz, (unsigned)szs, '-', binfmt (v, sz, szs, '-'));


    return 0;
}

/** simple return of binary string */
char *binstr (unsigned long n)
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;

    if (!n) {
        *s = '0';
        return s;
    }

    for (; n; n >>= 1)
        *--p = (n & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return p;
}

/** returns pointer to binary representation of 'n' zero padded to 'sz'.
 *  returns pointer to string contianing binary representation of
 *  unsigned 64-bit (or less ) value zero padded to 'sz' digits.
 */
char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz)
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;
    register size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *--p = (n>>i & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return p;
}

/** returns pointer to formatted binary representation of 'n' zero padded to 'sz'.
 *  returns pointer to string contianing formatted binary representation of
 *  unsigned 64-bit (or less ) value zero padded to 'sz' digits with char
 *  'sep' placed every 'szs' digits. (e.g. 10001010 -> 1000-1010).
 */
char *binfmt (unsigned long n, unsigned char sz, unsigned char szs, char sep) {

    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG * 2 + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;
    unsigned char i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        p--;
        if (i > 0 && szs > 0 && i % szs == 0)
            *p-- = sep;
        *p = (n >> i & 1) ? '1' : '0';
    }

    return p;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/binstrtst

 binstr (237)
 11101101

 binpad (237, 16)
 0000000011101101

 binfmt (237, 16, 4, -)
 0000-0000-1110-1101

 binpad (237, 32)
 00000000000000000000000011101101

 binfmt (237, 32, 8, -)
 00000000-00000000-00000000-11101101

 binpad (237, 64)
 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011101101

 binfmt (237, 64, 8, -)
 00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-11101101
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps. You can test with your 0x61 (decimal 97), e.g.:

```
$ ./bin/binstrtst 97

 binstr (97)
 1100001

 binpad (97, 16)
 0000000001100001

 binfmt (97, 16, 4, -)
 0000-0000-0110-0001

 binpad (97, 32)
 00000000000000000000000001100001

 binfmt (97, 32, 8, -)
 00000000-00000000-00000000-01100001

 binpad (97, 64)
 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100001

 binfmt (97, 64, 8, -)
 00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-01100001
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!
It most definitely helped. I will be sure to try those out.
Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. I have tried the various functions and tried them a number of different ways, but these seem to be the three I go back to any time I need a binary representation of a number. I have a couple more for IEEE-754 floating point binary formats, but the integer representations are the ones I use time and time again. For example, you can call the program and pass 97 as an argument to look at your number.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always expecting only 8-bits, you could use right shift operator, something like this:

```
a = a >> 8;
```

this will shift the bits to its right by 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm not quite sure where I would implement that into my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a 16bit mask on an 8bit char. If you cast it to an int before you do your bit operations it will work as you expect it to.

```
void printBin(char key_8) // key_8: 0x01100001
{
    int key_16 = key_8; // key_16: 0x0000000001100001
    int count;                                  
    int bits = 16;
    unsigned int mask = 1 << --bits; // mask: 0x1000000000000000            

    for(count = 0; count <= bits; count++)      
    {
        if(key_16 & mask)
        {
            printw("1");
        }
        else
        {
            printw("0");
        }

        key_16 <<= 1;
    }
}
```